# TuxGuitar Tuning?

Tags: guitar, software, tuxguitar

I have started using TuxGuitar, and the tuning has left be confused.

For example I have the option to select B1 to B9 tuning, instead of just B, is this an error or what are the difference between _1 to _9?

For more details check this screen-shot[image]:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program gives you the ability to choose how many strings you want, and then the tuning of each of these strings.

The numbers 1-9 refer to octaves. So, for instance, you could choose to tune a 12 string guitar by doubling each string at pitch or by doubling each string at an octave higher.

The pitches are named according to [Scientific Pitch Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_pitch_notation). Each octave receives a number and each pitch receives a letter.

Comment: Aha, you beat me to it. I'll just add that traditionally, middle C is designated as C4, however some old MIDI implementations referred to it as C3, so don't think you're going crazy if you ever plug in an old keyboard and see everything is displaced by an octave.